# Cannot open /dev/rfcomm1 : Host is down

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am working on raspberry PI and on Bluetooth. I am using old raspberry pi kernel as the new one has got some bugs that were not resolved with respect to the bluez daemon. At present my kernel version is 3.6.11.

I am using a USB bluetooth dongle and my sole purpose is to auto connect the bluetooth dongle when ever it is in range. For that i think i have to run a script in the backend on RPI that will keep on checking the existence of usb bluetooth dongle. I started from the very scratch. I installed bluez daemon using

```
apt-get install bluetooth bluez utils blueman
```

and then i used

```
hciconfig
```

which gives me that my bluetooth usb dongle is working fine. But when i did

```
hcitool scan
```

, it give me no device in range even though my Serial bluetooth Device was on. I wasn't able to find any device in vicinity. Also when i unplugged and plug the USB dongle again, i was able to scan the serial device , but when i repeat the process, i find the earlier condition of not finding any deice. I had find another useful [link](https://superuser.com/questions/476654/two-parts-linux-startup-script-to-connect-to-bluetooth-and-cron-to-keep-it-conn), but that need address of the bluetooth device that need to be connected. I want to automate this using hcitool scan, storing the output to the a file and then comparing it with already paired devices and their name. For that i need to figure out why `hcitool scan` is sometime working and sometime not. ?

Can some one help me in figuring out why this is happening. Is there any problem on 
hardware side i.e Bluetooth dongle is buggy or i had some problem in bluez utils.

Edit 1: While as of now, hcitool scan is giving me my remote device address but still i am getting the same issue of HOUST IS DOWN, '/dev/rfcomm1'. I am really not getting any idea of what to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what i did or what happened randomly, i am able to get the `hcitool` scan results after i used `sudo apt-get install python-bluez`. Also i find that hardware was a probable faulty thing i was having. When i switched the USB-BLuetooth dongle , things work fine.